# Presentation of amalgamated sum as a quotient of the direct sum

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, universal-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids, congruences

I am currently reading Arthur Ogus' "Lectures on Logarithmic Algebraic Geometry" (https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/preprints/log_book/logbook.pdf).
I'm trying to understand why the amalgamated sum of two monoid morphisms $P→Q_i$ possesses a presentation as a quotient of the direct sum:

$$Q_1⊕_PQ_2=Q_1⊕Q_2/E$$

with $E$
being a congruence relation on $Q_1⊕Q_2$. In Proposition 1.1.4 it is shown how the relation looks like, but in the proof it is already taken for granted that the quotient exists. A certain natural map $Q_1⊕Q_2→Q_1⊕_PQ_2$ is mentioned, which I can't comprehend. Why does such a presentation exist?
I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: Not sure if I got your doubt about the proof of P1.1.4. , but, that the quotient exists, it is not really taken for granted: $E$ is a congruence, and at the beginning of the section it is explained why co-equalizers of homomorphisms of monoids (in particular, quotients wrto a congruence) do always exist. Note that it is a general fact in any category that any inductive limit  can be construct by means of a co-equailzer and a co-product.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to use the definition of the amalgamated sum as the coequalizer of the two maps $P \rightarrow Q_1⊕Q_2$? I prefer the idea of thinking of the amalgamated sum as the pair of morphisms $Q_i \rightarrow Q_1⊕_P Q_2$ making the diagram universally commute but I guess in this scenario I miss the link to the quotient. Thx for your help!

Comment: The construction of pushouts via coproducts and coequalizers (or dually, the construction of pullbacks via products and equalizers) is often treated separately from the general construction of colimits via coproducts and coequalizers - cf. [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pullback_as_Equalizer). It may be easier to grasp in dual form first -- the pullback of $f$ and $g$ is the equalizer of $f \times g$ with the diagonal: just think of how it works in $Set$. Dually, the pushout can be constructed by first taking the coproduct and then making the necessary identifications via a coequalizer.